# NoClassDefFound error using Jode obfuscator

Tags: java, obfuscation, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using jode's obfuscator in an attempt to obfuscate all of the class files in my jar. I've packaged all the class files in the jar, so that I can use the config to specify what I need loading, and what I need preserving.

Here is my package hierarchy:

```
src
src.loading
src.loading.org
src.loading.sign
```

Here's what I've specified as my wildcards:

```
load = new WildCard { value = "src.*" }
preserve = new WildCard { value = "src.loading.org.*" }
```

And this is the error I get (Decompiling too. It's the only class.)

```
C:\Users\Kieran\Desktop\jode>java jode.obfuscator.Main project.jos
Jode (c) 1998-2001 Jochen Hoenicke <jochen@gnu.org>
used before: 479080
Loading and preserving classes
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: src.loading.Class48
        at jode.bytecode.ClassInfo.loadInfo(ClassInfo.java:631)
        at jode.obfuscator.ClassIdentifier.initClass(ClassIdentifier.java:371)


Exception while decompiling:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: src.loading.Class48
    at jode.bytecode.ClassInfo.loadInfo(ClassInfo.java:631)
    at jode.decompiler.ClassAnalyzer.<init>(ClassAnalyzer.java:86)
    at jode.decompiler.ClassAnalyzer.<init>(ClassAnalyzer.java:123)
    at jode.decompiler.Decompiler.decompile(Decompiler.java:191)
    at jode.swingui.Main.run(Main.java:204)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The class does exist, and I the jar file is fully functional. Why am I getting this error?

This specific class is using reflection, to access java.lang.Runtime, could this be the issue...?

Comment: A NoClassDefFoundError is usually due to ClassNotFoundException or ExceptionInInitializerError. Did you see any of these in stacktrace?

Comment: Nope, that's the only error I'm getting, although Class48 is fine, and all of its functions

Comment: You need to provide the jar to your classpath. Suggest you to refer this - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Comment: It's already in my classpath, also when decompiling all of the classes, it's the only class that doesn't decompile.